# Xaml, How to bind a list of buttons over an image in different coordination

Tags: xaml, data-binding, coordinates, winrt-xaml

For a windows 8 Apps, i need to put a list of buttons over an image. Each button has   CoordinateX and  CoordinateY properties. I use a gridView to bind  to the list of buttons.
I need to have the result as below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
     <Canvas>  
         <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/red.png" Stretch="None"  ></Image>

          <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" 
                    SelectionMode="None" IsSwipeEnabled="false"  IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Button" Padding="0">                            
          <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="194" Height="51" Background="Gray" Canvas.Left="{Binding CoordinateX}" Canvas.Top="{Binding CoordinateY}"></Button>                    
                </DataTemplate>
          </GridView.ItemTemplate>
          </GridView>                      
     </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

But this is what i get after running the app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ites Likely that at runtime before the X and Y co-ordinates can be set for the items within the GridView, the GridView itself has its properties applied. 
Since 
1) the GridView is intended to be used for oganization control 
and 
2) you havent forced the Grid to fill the view space

what you're left with is a GridView that acts as it wishes and limits the ability of its items to conform to your style, should the style attempt to force the items collection to live outside the bounds of the control.

You could try to set the GridView's Horizontal Alignment property but even if it happens to work, its probably a better bet to use a less organized content control like the more basic ItemsPresenter.

Which ever control you end up using... make sure to check for /set the HorizontalContentAlignment & VerticalContentAlignment properties if they exist.